# How to disable a specific calendars notification?

Tags: notifications, calendar

How can I disable the notifications for a specific calendar only?

Example: 
I have the calendar of my girlfriend synced to my phone to know the times she is at home, working, etc. Now I get all the notifications about the events from her calendar. I want to get notifications for my calendar only, but not for hers.

Maybe this is important too:
I am using a Davical server and sync my calendars over [caldav sync](http://dmfs.org/caldav/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use e.g. [Calendar Event Reminder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.foobarsoft.calendareventreminder), and disable notifications in the default/stock calendar. With *CER*, you can setup reminders for each calendar separately, and even deactivate alerts for calendars you don't want to be alerted for (in your case, the "work" calendar).

The added plus is you will never miss an alert anymore, as you can configure *CER* to annoy you until you shut the alert of manually. I've bought the app when it was still payed, and it never let me down.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to do that with the native calendar -- but at least this is a free solution, though it takes an extra app :)

Comment: The app now costs $2.79, no longer a free solution.

Comment: Yupp, seems like. I switched to [Business Calendar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/business-calendar/netgenius.bizcal) about a year ago (even bought the license), and disabled "alerts" from the default calendar. Not sure whether that was already possible with the free version, but it's worth a try. Apart from that, you might wish to take a look at my list of [Kalender-Alarm-Fixes](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=13).

Comment: I opted for a different app than OP mentioned, but it has the same exact name. The developer is Milan Sillik. It requires an in-app purchase to selectively disable alerts for certain calendars.

I think the reality is any replacement reminder app will do the job here, but OP's approach is the best fit until Google decides to address this issue in their UI.