# How can I select a calendar to get alerts when I have more than one?

Tags: google-calendar, alerts

Say I have 2 calendars. 1 for my personal stuff and 2 for my work related.
Is there a way that I could only choose to get alerts from one for time being. Later, add or switch calendars?
I am using Google Calendar.

Comment: You decide on an event by event basis whether you get reminders or not. It's really nothing to do with the calendar.

Comment: @AlEverett well... Mostly right in theory. But practically, it's still possible. See my anser to [How to disable a specific calendars notification?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37557/16575)

Comment: You could hide the other calendar. Then, you wouldn't get alerts from them. Is that a good alternative?